# Julia equivalent of R's paste() function

Tags: julia

Is there a function in Julia that behaves like R's `paste()` function? In particular, if we give the function two vectors, it would return a single vector with the element-wise concatenation of the two input vectors.

I've looked around and can't seem to find the answer for this in the docs or otherwise. [An older post](http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2012/04/09/comparing-julia-and-rs-vocabularies/) by John Myles White suggests that Julia's `join()` function is the closest analogue, but it seems to work only on pairs of strings, not element-wise on vectors of strings.

For now, I'm just using the function below that loops over elements calling `join()`, but I'm wondering if there is a better approach.

```julia-lang
x = ["aa", "bb", "cc"]
y = ["dd", "ee", "ff"]

function mypaste(v1, v2)
    n = length(v1)
    res = Array{ASCIIString}(n)
    for i = 1:n
        res[i] = join([v1[i], v2[i]])
    end
    return res
end

mypaste(x, y)
```

Running `mypaste()` gives us the output below, as desired.

```julia
3-element Array{ASCIIString,1}:
 "aadd"
 "bbee"
 "ccff"
```

Is there a good alternative? Am I misunderstanding the `join()` function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think I'd use `join` at all.  Join is used to combine strings within one collection; you're after concatenation of strings across two different collections. So while it's easy (and efficient) to create the temporary collections you need for `join` with `zip`, you can avoid it by using the `string` function or multiplication:

```
julia> map(string, x, y)
3-element Array{ASCIIString,1}:
 "aadd"
 "bbee"
 "ccff"

julia> map(*, x, y)
3-element Array{ASCIIString,1}:
 "aadd"
 "bbee"
 "ccff"
```

Even better (but perhaps too clever by half), there's the broadcasting element-wise multiplication operator `.*`:

```
julia> x .* y
3-element Array{ASCIIString,1}:
 "aadd"
 "bbee"
 "ccff"
```

Comment: But this would be the `paste0()` function in R. How can you make the map function put a space between "aa" and "dd"?

Comment: I used `x.*" ".*y` but I still wonder how to do it with map function

Comment: @JorgeParedes, `map` requires all its arguments are the same size.  You can use `broadcast(*, x, " ", y)` to do the same thing as the `.*` version you have above.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a list comprehension and [`zip`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/collections/#Base.zip) to get the pairs:

```
julia> x = ["aa", "bb", "cc"];

julia> y = ["dd", "ee", "ff"];

julia> [join(i) for i=zip(x,y)]
3-element Array{ByteString,1}:
 "aadd"
 "bbee"
 "ccff"
```

Answer (score 4):

`map` could be used. The one-liner is `map(join,zip(x,y))`. As in the following example, which also adds `z`:

```
julia> x = ["aa","bb","cc"];

julia> y = ["dd","ee","ff"];

julia> z = ["gg","hh","ii"];

julia> map(join,zip(x,y,z))
3-element Array{Any,1}:
 "aaddgg"
 "bbeehh"
 "ccffii"
```

(see @DSM answer for list comprehension)